# Do the Google login and Facebook login API set third party (non-essential) cookies

Tags: authentication, cookies

I'm building a non-commercial, ad-free website, and want to add Google+ login and Facebook login apart from a custom (email) login.

I wonder if these login API's set third party cookies?

Because if they do, I would have to add an 'accept cookies' popup to the site to stay GDPR compliant (in Europe) - and that would be a major sacrifice.

Thanks!